# How do I architecture an asp.net multi web-site solution?

Tags: asp.net, architecture

I have a web site solution (asp.net) that runs on a SQL server database. I have several of those installations running and i want to create an administration module which can monitor and interact with them all. - and if all goes well - push/upgrade an installation to FTP/SQL.

What is the best approach to architecturing this?

- SHould i simpley just integrate with the database on each installation (easiest approach as i see it) but this will give problems when/if I upgrade the database model
- Should I write a webservice which interacts with the database and i "simply" connect with this webservice on each website when i need to administer it?

Any solutions i havent thought about is very welcome

/Brian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latter would be a better approach as this would give you independence from any underlying customisations to the installations.

Answer (score 0):

I agree abstract the implementation into a webservice, and then use something like the enterprise library to interact with the datastore.

This will give you a good framework to work from and should help decouple your application, resulting in more flexiblity moving forward.